# How to code a superclass field that accepts multiple subclasses?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8, openerp-8

I want to have a superclass that will be inherited by subclasses.

Let's say I want the superclass `mother` to be inherited by `child.a` and `child.b`.

So I make these classes

mother:

```
class mother(osv.osv):

    _name           = "mother"

mother()
```

child.a:

```
class child_a(osv.osv):

    _name           = "child.a"
    _inherit        = "mother"

child_a()
```

child.b:

```
class child_b(osv.osv):

    _name           = "child.b"
    _inherit        = "mother"

child_b()
```

now let's say I have a class `a` that have a `many2one` connection to `mother`

```
class a(osv.osv):

    _name           = "a"
    _columns        = {
        'mother' : fields.many2one('mother', 'Mother'),
    }

a()
```

Does `mother` field accept both class `child.a` and `child.b`. If yes how to code the create and write methods. If not how do I achieve this in any other way? (field accepting multiple subclasses)

Answer (score 2):

No, a `many2one` referencing `mother` can't address records of `class.a`or `class.b`.

The inheritance method used for `class.a` and `class.b` actually copies the `mother` features. They create two new independent tables, copy of `mother`, containing independent data sets.

This means that the classes are not interchangeable in any way.
Records in `child.a` are not present in `mother`and vice-versa.

What you describe can be achieved with [delegation inheritance](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#inheritance-and-extension) - you can think that as `class.x` having a `mother` class "embedded" in it, through a special `many2one` relation.

This way, when you create a new `class.x` record, a new `mother` record is also implicitly created.

But this works one way: creating a new `mother` record does not create a `class.x` record.

An [example of delegation inheritance](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py#L146) in the core modules is `res.users`: a User "embeds" a Partner. When a new user is created, a new Partner is also created  for it.

Many2one relations to Partners will also be able to reference the User embedded Partners.  But many2one relations to Users will not be able to reference Partners that are not Users.

Comment: From the example two `many2one` fields are added to the `mother` but it doesn't enforce the creation of `mother` for every time a child is created does it? Isn't it more reasonable to add a required `many2one mother` field to the child instead? I still don't understand the concept.

Comment: The trick is to not think about it as actual "object inheritance", just instead think of "copying a model". To be honest, that inheritance method is only useful to extend a class in place. To create a derived class you should really use delegation inheritance.

Comment: But both derived classes (child_a,child_b) won't fit into one `many2one mother field` in model `a` will they?

Comment: `child_a` and `child_b` records both create and have "embedded" a `mother` record. A Many2one to `mother` can reference it's records created by `child_a` and `child_b` although afaik won't have dot-notation access to their child specific fields.

Comment: I kinda get the idea now, but I'm still unsure. From your suggestion I think the idea is to give access to the child classes from the mother class. But doesn't that mean that I need to edit my mother class every time a new child class is created which defeats the purpose of having an abstraction in the first place. Can you give an example based on my classes just to make sure I get the idea right.

Comment: Yes it can be confusing, I tried to give a real example in the answer.

Comment: Thank you it has gotten clearer now, Now from the example how do I handle partner creation through user creation? How do I fill all the required fields of partner? And how do I show partner field in the view? Using a related field?